# Get-QADUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

I am trying to take users from AD with some filter criteria but while executing Get-QADUser' command I am getting following error.

```
Get-QADUser : The term 'Get-QADUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-QADUser
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-QADUser:String) [], CommandNotFoundExce 
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Can Anybody tel me how to resolve this?

I using following reference link

http://wiki.powergui.org/index.php/Get-QADUser

Comment: You should consider using the supported Microsoft ActiveDirectory module for working with AD, rather than the QAD tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[QAD cmdlets FAQ](http://wiki.powergui.org/index.php/QAD_cmdlets_FAQ)

> **To load QAD cmdlets for one particular script:**
>
> Add this line in the beginning of the script:
>
> ```
> Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement -ErrorAction Stop
> ```
>
> **To make QAD cmdlets available for all your scripts on a particular computer:**
>
> Open your PowerShell profile (for example, by starting PowerGUI Script Editor and selecting File / Open Current User Profile). Add this line to the profile code:
>
> ```
> Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement -ErrorAction Stop
> ```

PS. Original Quest article was recommending `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` but I cannot agree with such.

Comment: Thanks for response  .I did the steps as per your solution But still its showing same error .

Comment: I recommend you read an introduction into PowerShell before you continue. Start with the [Tutorials](http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/).

Comment: Hey Thanks.  Problem has been resolved Ad Management was not installed.I installed and work with your solution .Thanks lot